# How do I give an element both absolute and sticky positioning at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```html
<div>
    content...
    content...
    content...
    <div>
        a bit more important content which is absolutely positioned
    </div>
    content...
    content...
</div>
```

```css
p {
    margin-left: 300px;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: .5rem;
    margin: .5rem;
}

pre {
    position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <div class='container'>
        <pre><code>Important stuff here</code></pre>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `.container` div is absolutely positioned. What I want to do next is make the div sticky, ie. when it reaches the top of the screen, it will stick there while the content keeps scrolling. I've tried swapping the styles of `.container` and `pre`, but it didn't work. How can I fix this? JavaScript solutions are OK.

Comment: @Ouroborus I applied the styles of `.container` to `pre` and vice versa. It had the same effect

Comment: @Ouroborus I could do that, but I was looking for a plain CSS solution. I'll see if anybody comes up with a way to do this.

Comment: @Ouroborus there is a CSS solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a float element and then use sticky:

```css
p {
    margin-left: 300px;
}

.container {
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: .5rem;
    margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <div class='container'>
        <pre><code>Important stuff here</code></pre>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis eveniet dolorem aliquam minus eum alias. Et odit tenetur perferendis id est sapiente, omnis soluta dicta neque debitis, optio porro excepturi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia quis at consectetur corrupti eum eius numquam obcaecati explicabo veritatis, deserunt dicta debitis in blanditiis porro, voluptas eveniet quas. Quasi!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the restrictions on this technique? It appears to work as presented however this isn't the usual solution for this common problem.

Comment: @Ouroborus I don't see any restriction. It's not really a *technique* on its own. It's only 2 CSS properties I used to achieve the needed resutl

Comment: Perhaps I'm overthinking this. In my experience, there's typically also a need to use multiple elements or to have them stop being sticky after a certain point. Asker doesn't mention either of these.